# Research indicating that student evaluations should be used for formative rather than summative purposes?

Tags: evaluation, course-evaluation, evaluation-criteria

I had a conversation a while back in which someone referred to research indicating that student evaluations of faculty should ideally be used for formative rather than summative evaluation (i.e. in making a plan for professional development, rather than for deciding things like promotion or merit).  I want to find a reference, but can't seem to locate one specifically on this point (although I can find lots that point out various reasons student evaluations are flawed).  Does anyone know of a reference for this argument?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might page through some of the existing Q&A here using the course-evaluation tag, as related discussions have come up before. Most answers are not referenced, but some are, for example this answer https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/161448/63475 has a reference that is critical of student evaluations as a measure of learning. I think "should be used" is necessarily going to be opinion-based and not something you can *research*, because it depends on your criteria for "should". Happy students might be desirable to the person deciding on promotions.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you so much!  I will check this out!